# Can't run a working shell script from inside Perl

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell

I have a shell script `makecsv.sh` that runs correctly alone but fails when called from within Perl.

This is the message it gives when I run `makecsv.sh` from the Perl script:

```
fr call
Source file does not exist

Usage: fr -s <source_file> -o <output_file>
   -s <source_file> - Input file which has Counter Information
   -o <output_file> - Comma separated output file

third move
mv: cannot access /home/ateam/.../SAM5_01-05-  2016_11:07:29.csv
/home/ateam/.../SAM5_01-05-2016_11:07:29.xcm: No such   file or directory
cp: cannot access /home/ateam/.../SAMlog/ /home/ateam/.../SAM5_01-05-2016_11:07:29.csv
md5sum: /home/ateam/.../SAM5_01-05-2016_11:07:29.csv: No such file or directory
/home/ateam/.../SAM5_01-05-2016_11:07:29.csv: No such file or directory
```

This is a listing of the directory containing the `fr` node

```
drwxrwxr-x   4 ateam    ateam       4096 May  1 11:12 ./
drwxr-xr-x   3 ateam    ateam       4096 Mar 17 11:18 ../
lrwxrwxrwx   1 ateam    ateam          7 Mar 12 19:13 c -> counter*
-rwxrwxr-x   1 ateam    ateam       1974 Mar 12 19:04 counter*
-rwxrwxr-x   1 ateam    ateam        134 Mar 21 11:22 e*
-rw-rw-r--   1 ateam    ateam    25152020 Mar 21 11:22 enb
-rw-rw-r--   1 ateam    ateam    1880872 Mar 21 11:21 enb283.xml
-rwxrwxr-x   1 ateam    ateam        811 Mar 28 11:59 expftp*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 ateam    ateam          7 Mar 17 11:23 fr -> fruinfo*
-rw-rw-r--   1 ateam    ateam      75753 Mar 22 13:07 fru_0322.xls
-rwxrwxr-x   1 ateam    ateam       2878 Apr 21 22:16 fruinfo*
drwxrwxr-x   2 ateam    ateam       4096 May  1 11:12 md5sum/
...
```

I do not understand what this directory item is

```
 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ateam    ateam          7 Mar 17 11:23 fr -> fruinfo*
```

---

A little more information.

In the shell script, the call to `fr` looks like this

```
fr -s "$newfile" -o "$frufile"
```

and the shebang line is this

```
#!/bin/bash
```

In the Perl file, the shell script is called like this

```
my $cmd = qq(bash makecsv.sh $initdir$sam.xcm $csvdest);
print $cmd, "\n";
#system 'bash makecsv.sh ${initdir}${sam}.xcm $csvdest';
system($cmd);
```

The variables above are all doubled quoted, if that helps.

Comment: Btw, both makecsv.sh and the perl script are in the same directory. The fr file listing shown above is in a different dir.

Comment: Try adding `echo "DEBUG: newfile: $newfile"` just before the `fr` call in the `makecsv.sh` and see what is printed when you run `makecsv.sh` from shell and from Perl script.

Comment: Ok. I will try that. Do you know what the fruinfo and counter files are doing with the fr and c parts?

Comment: `fr` and `c` are symbolic links to `fruinfo` and `counter` respectively. This means that for example to run `fruinfo`, users can use `./fruinfo` or `./fr` and the same binary will be executed. Wikipedia has more on Unix symbolic links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#POSIX_and_Unix-like_operating_systems

Comment: @bart When I run makecsv.sh on its own, it prints: DEBUG: newfile: SAM6_01-05-2016_12:40:05.xcm. When I run it from inside PERL, it prints the whole file path to the file. I'm not sure why its doing that though.

Comment: Please would you just show all of `makecsv.sh` and all of your Perl script?

Comment: What are `fr call` and `third move`? Is that annotation from by you, or is it part of the output?

Comment: The spaces in the message `mv: cannot access /home/ateam/.../SAM5_01-05-  2016_11:07:29.csv` are suspicious. Have you just copied the text wrongly?  I would expect your file name to look like `SAM5_01-05-2016_11:07:29.csv` without the spaces before the year. Does that file or anything like it exist?

Comment: "fr call" and "third move" (for the mv cmds in the script are outputs from makecsv.sh). I have fully figured the solution though. The second argument that I am sending in the Perl script needs to only be the filename, not the absolute path to the filename. I did not take that into consideration...

Comment: @Borodin Ahh. I see what you mean. That file does not exist. That was just an copying over error... apologies.

Comment: @noc_coder: It is a very poor Perl script that won't handle absolute file paths properly. Are you interested in getting it fixed? Meanwhile, if you have a solution to your problem then please write it up as an answer and accept it so that others can benefit from your experience.

Answer (score 0):

From this call to 'system' inside of the Perl script, I was adding the $initdir variable unnecessarily.

```
my $cmd = qq(bash makecsv.sh $initdir$sam.xcm $csvdest);
print $cmd, "\n"; 
system($cmd);
```

I changed the line that initializes $cmd to this and it worked:

```
 my $cmd = qq(bash makecsv.sh $sam.xcm $csvdest);
```

Now as for what makecsv.sh looks like, the program looks like this. I shortened the directories purposely.

```
#!/bin/bash
#/bin/env sh
# makecsv.sh /path/to/source/ /path/to/destination/

SRC=$1
DST=$2

# separate filename from ext
filename="${SRC%.*}"
extension="${SRC##*.}"

NOW="$(date +'%d-%m-%Y_%T')"
newfile="${filename}_${NOW}.$extension"

mv -f "$SRC" "$newfile"
mv -f "$newfile" "$DST"
#mv -f "${filename}_${NOW}.$extension" "$DST"

cd $DST
# rename file with .csv ext (without the .xcm)
noExt="${newfile%.*}"
frufile="${noExt}.csv"
fr -s "$newfile" -o "$frufile"

mv "$frufile" "/home/.../SAMlog"
rm "$newfile"

# remove files older than 90 days
find /home/..../SAMlog -type f -mtime +90 -exec rm {} \;

# create a md5sum stored in a file for frufile
cp /home/.../SAMlog/"$frufile" "${DST}/md5sum"
cd "${DST}/md5sum"
# create a fingerprint for the new frufile
md5file="${noExt}.md5"
touch "$md5file"
md5sum "$frufile" > "$md5file"
rm "$frufile"

# check for md5sum files older than 1 day and delete them
# only ever need to keep the sums of the current day and the previous one for cmp
find /home/.../md5sum -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

This code was never supposed to accept a fullpath, although I wrote that at the top it should. So, I will change that to accept full paths.